# IBOutlet not coming

Tags: ios, iphone

I have an `FYImageSequence` class which inherits `UIImageView`. But still I can't connect it as an outlet in storyboard. This is what is in my header file.

```
@interface FVImageSequence : UIImageView {
    NSString *prefix;
    int numberOfImages;
    int current;
    int previous;
    NSString *extension;
    int increment;
}
```

In the view controller I have

```
IBOutlet FVImageSequence *imageSquence;
```

There is no error, but I am not able to see the outlet when I connect from storyboard.

Comment: Did you changed the class of UIImageView to FVImageSequence in StoryBoard?

Answer (score 2):

Answer is pretty simple ..Since you inherited,Change your classname to the purticular class in nib [better use `UIView` and than adding `UIImageView` ] and then only the properties can be accessed

Answer (score 1):

Change your class name of Class Property of ViewController, and also change your imageview class imageView to FVImageSequence in storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

change your class from `UIIMageView` to `FVImageSequence` in storyboard, that will solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Set your class name in Class property of View Controller in storyView.